# Hide subcommand group

Tags: rust, clap

I have code like this:

```rust
#[derive(Subcommand)]
pub enum MyTool {
    Clean(CleanPackage),
    Compile(CompilePackage),
    #[clap(subcommand)]
    Coverage(coverage::CoveragePackage),
    #[clap(subcommand)]
    Show(show::ShowTool),
    Test(TestPackage),
    View(ViewFunction),
}
```

I want the subcommand group under `show` to be hidden from help text. I have tried the following:

```rust
#[clap(subcommand, hidden)]
```

```rust
#[clap(subcommand, hide)]
```

But neither of these work. Is what I want to do possible with clap, specifically with the "structopt style" of representing the argument parser?

I'm using clap version 3.2.23.

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out, turns out you need to do this:

```rust
#[clap(subcommand, hide(true))]
```

This also works:

```rust
#[clap(subcommand, hide = true)]
```